# Empty borderless window not showing?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to use the following code to show an empty border-less window, but no windows appear at all. I followed the documentation:

```
HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST,NULL,NULL,WS_POPUP,0,0,1000,1000,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
```

Comment: You might want a class name...

Comment: If it's empty and borderless, what do you expect to see?

Comment: @HotLicks: A white box.

Comment: Did you start a message pump that services this window?

Answer (score 0):

```
HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST, L"STATIC", NULL, WS_POPUPWINDOW, 0, 0, 100, 100, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
```